# Increase upload file size in .NET core 3.1 Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

Currently, I am working with .NET core web API and need to upload file size unlimited.
I have searched for its solution but there is no exact documentation on it.

Tried the below options.

*#1st Approach*

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{
services.Configure(x =>
{
x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});

services.AddMvc();
}

*#2nd Approach*

```
[HttpPost]
```

[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]

It would be great if anyone has a reference for this.

Comment: try adding these 2 ```[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147383648)]
        [RequestSizeLimit(2147383648)]``` together

Comment: You really don't want it to be unlimited. What if someone tries to upload a 2GB file? Or worse, what if someone makes a call and just starts writing random bytes to the stream until your API crashes? That's a *very* common attack. Even if you do need to accept such large files, uploading GB-sized data in one call can easily fail

Comment: Find a *reasonable limit* and set it, to ensure your Web API isn't vulnerable to attacks. If you really want to accept multi-GB data it's probably better to allow the poster to make partial uploads instead, posting specific ranges of the file each time. This would allow retries in case of failures. It's something all download/upload tools do. You'd have to handle the Range header for this.

Comment: Reference, since you asked for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1. If this is for an API, consider asking for a URL and use it to download the file. If you're consuming the API, upload directly to something like Azure Blob Storage, AWS S3, etc. and pass that URL to the API.